# ggplot/qqplotr returns error on data format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a QQ and/or PP plot from the air_time data inside the flights data frame belonging to the nycflights13 package. I am using ggplot with [qqplotr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qqplotr/vignettes/introduction.html).

This is my code:

```
library(nycflights13)
library(qqplotr)

ggplot(data = flights$air_time, mapping = aes(sample = norm)) +
  stat_qq_band() +
  stat_qq_line() +
  stat_qq_point() +
  labs(x = "Theoretical Quantiles", y = "Sample Quantiles")
```

When I try to run this I get the error:

```
Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not a numeric vector
```

What is causing this error and how do I fix it? I normally call ggplot as follows so I do not know if there could be issues there:

```
ggplot(flights, air_time, aes(sample = norm))
```

Comment: As the error messages says, `flights$air_time` is a numeric vector and not a `data.frame`. Also I highly doubt that you *normally call ggplot as follows* `ggplot(flights, air_time, aes(sample = norm))`

Comment: @dario how would I turn it into a data frame. I tried using the function data.frame() but that did not work out good.

Comment: But `flights` **is** already a data.frame. Please check the syntax for calls to `ggplot`. The code you think is working is not i.e. `ggplot(flights, air_time, aes(sample = norm))` does **not** work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the sample argument to reflect the variable inside the data.

```
Air_time <- flights[, "air_time"] # Or select a random sample to save time
ggplot(data = Air_time, mapping = aes(sample = air_time)) +
  stat_qq_band() +
  stat_qq_line() +
  stat_qq_point()
```

Comment: While your answer is perfectly fine, maybe for didactic reasons `ggplot(data = flights, mapping = aes(sample = air_time)) + etc` is more explicit ;)

Comment: I just noticed you are not using sample = norm as in the vignette. Does this still produce the correct plot?

Comment: @dario. I wanted to give the OP the chance to select a random sample of the data since it was rather large ;)

Comment: @RuudVerhoef. The mapping argument to sample must be a valid variable within the data. So putting sample=norm will give an error. The vignette is using a data frame called smp, which contains one variable named "norm".

Comment: And the default distribution is "normal" as documented in the help page.